# Windows 7 stuck in a startup repair loop

Tags: boot

Hi my computer is stuck in a startup repair loop. It's been stuck like this for hours. When it first turns on I get the blue screen i.e.  Then it immediately goes into "Windows is loading files..." Startup repair runs and after about ten seconds I get 2 screens.

One says `"Startup Repair can I repair this computer automatically. Sending more information can help...."` Opening problem details reveals;

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: StartupRepairOffline
Problem signature 01: 0.0.0.0
Problem signature 02: 6.1.7600.16385
Problem signature 03: unknown
Problem signature 04: -1
Problem signature 05: AutoFailover
Problem signature 06: 1
Problem signature 07: OsVersionMismatch
OS version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Locale ID: 1033
```

The second screen says `"Startup Repair could not detect a problem. If you have recently attached a device..."` Clicking View repair diagnostics and repair details reveals;

```
Root cause found: The operating system version is incompatible with Startup Repair.
```

Check for updates, System disk test, Disk failure diagnosis, Disk metadata test, Target OS test, and Volume content check all come up with error code 0x0.

I do not have the Windows installation disk, but I do have another computer and a USB Flash Drive.

Comment: looks like you use a Win7 RTM ISO/DVD to repair Windows7Sp1 install. So get a Win7 Sp1 ISO.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: get Win7 Sp1 ISo from here: https://tb.rg-adguard.net/

Comment: Will this delete all my personal files? Also, would I put it on my USB?

Comment: it tries to repair Boot related data of Windows. But it is always good to have backups